# What is going wrong with this 50/51 Problem?

Tags: c#

Problem : I have total rupees 50 and i buy 3 product and each product have different price. When i buy a product i write princes i-e Price_Remaining and Price_Consume. Finally when i calculate both list i am getting 50 on one side and 51 on other side ?

Actually this is a problem of mathematics but i implemented it in a C# Code and i personally don't know why i getting 50 on one side and 51 on other side ? If someone know this: Share with me. (Thanks)

> All the problem Details are given inside a Code Comments.

```
namespace Fifty_And_FiftyOne_Problem
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int TotalRupees = 50; // Rs.50/-
            int Sum_Of_totalConsume = 0;
            int Sum_Of_totalRemaining = 0;
            // Comsume.
            List<int> totalOfCosume = new List<int>();

            // Remaining.
            List<int> totalRemaining = new List<int>();

            // Product 1. Price = 20/-
            // Buyed Product 1. 
            // 50 - 20 = 30

            // After executing the below line : TotalRupees = 30
            TotalRupees = TotalRupees - 20;

            totalOfCosume.Add(20);
            totalRemaining.Add(30);

            // Product 2. Price = 15/-
            // Buyed Product 2.
            // 30 - 15 = 15.

            // After executing the below line : TotalRupees = 15.
            TotalRupees = TotalRupees - 15;

            totalOfCosume.Add(15);
            totalRemaining.Add(15);

            // Product 3. Price = 9/-
            // Buyed Product 3.
            // 15 - 9 = 6.

            //// After executing the below line : TotalRupees = 6.
            TotalRupees = TotalRupees - 9;

            totalOfCosume.Add(9);
            totalRemaining.Add(6);

            // Product 4. Price = 6/-
            // Buyed Product 3.
            // 6 - 6 = 0.

            //// After executing the below line : TotalRupees = 0.
            TotalRupees = TotalRupees - 6;

            totalOfCosume.Add(6);
            totalRemaining.Add(0);

            Console.WriteLine("Total Cosume :");
            foreach (var item in totalOfCosume)
            {
                Sum_Of_totalConsume = Sum_Of_totalConsume + item;
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("_____");
            Console.WriteLine(Sum_Of_totalConsume);


            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Total Of Remaining :");
            foreach (var item in totalRemaining)
            {
                Sum_Of_totalRemaining = Sum_Of_totalRemaining + item;
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("_____");
            Console.WriteLine(Sum_Of_totalRemaining);

        }
    }
}
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: There is no logical reason that `totalRemaining` should sum to `50`. It only indicates how many Rupees were left at different points in time. The sum of these values has no meaningful value. The fact that it is close to the sum of `totalConsume` is a coincidence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it's silly math and they are not meant to be equal.

If you were to work with this and take 1 from `TotalRupees` until no more remain you would have

`Total Consume: 50`
`Total Remaining as 1225`

Hope this helps?